# ionViewWillEnter error: URI malformed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, uri

I'm getting this error

> 'Page' ionViewWillEnter error: URI malformed

Which stops my app from working. I don't know what's going on. This is my ionic info and a screenshot about the error .

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.6
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

[image: screenshot about the error]

Comment: Is this happening on app initialization or during an action in the action?

Comment: during an action. for example. I have 4 tabs. I if change from tab 1 to tab 2 I got this. @arkade

Answer (score 1):

I already fixed! the reason is aws-cognito-identity.min.js.

just change this library for aws-cognito-identity.js

you can get the library from https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js

[image: Error URI malformed]